# Vue.js send data to a child component and display them

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm beginning with vue.js and I don't understand why my infos are not sent to the child component. I tried several differents things and it's not working. I think I'm not that far but I can't figure it out :
*App.vue*

```js
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <Header/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <Services v-bind:services="services"></Services>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Header from "./components/Header.vue";
    import Services from "@/components/Service";

    export default {
        nam: 'App',
        components: {
            Services,
            Header,
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                services: [{
                    title: "Logo flatdesign",
                    description: "Je fais de super flatdesign",
                    image: "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_gig_cards_web_x2,q_auto,f_auto/gigs/22527722/original/3b5876ffb817872561d9eba6788dced76cb78224.jpg",
                    price: 6.7,
                    rate: 4,
                    id:1
                },{
                    title: "Logo rapide",
                    description: "Je fais vite un logo",
                    image: "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_gig_cards_web_x2,q_auto,f_auto/gigs/142024147/original/2abc0f9433df4f98790707a591772e56bf8777a1.jpg",
                    price: 5.5,
                    rate: 3,
                    id:2
                },{
                    title: "Logo flatdesign",
                    description: "Je fais de super flatdesign",
                    image: "https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_gig_cards_web_x2,q_auto,f_auto/gigs/22527722/original/3b5876ffb817872561d9eba6788dced76cb78224.jpg",
                    price: 6.7,
                    rate: 4,
                    id:3
                }]
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<style>
</style>
```

*Service.vue*

```js
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" v-for="service in services" v-bind:key="service.id">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <img :src="service.image" height="100%" width="100%">
                    <h4>
                        {{service.title}}
                    </h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col rate">
                            {{service.rate}} ★
                        </div>
                        <div class="col price">
                            {{service.price}} €
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
</script>

<style scoped>
    .rate{
        color: yellow;
    }
    .price{
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Thank you so much for your help :) !

Comment: where is your script for the child component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your child component's `script` to define the passed `prop` before using it:

```
export default {
  name: "Service",
  props: ['services']
};
```